# Inode file system biggest storeable file

Tags: filesystems, store, inode

If I use **inode** file system, and I have only **55** free block, than **how big** is the biggest file, that I can store?

Answer (score 0):

As Inode keep references to all the data blocks where corresponding file data is stored,you can store file which can be accommodated by these 55 free blocks. Also file size depends size of blocks.

Comment: My teacher said, that the answer is 54, because 1 block is needed for the inode table.